# Aparecer elementos de un array uno tras otro

Tags: java, processing

Tengo un código muy sencillo en el que aparecen tantas elipses como marca el bucle for. Necesito que cada elipse aparezca una detrás de otra, primero una después otra y así hasta llegar a las 10, no todas a la vez. No sé si tendrá algo que ver con el tiempo. Soy muy principiante en Processing. Muchas gracias.

```
int i;
int j;
int num;
int [] miarray;

void setup(){
  size(500,200);
  i=0;
  j=0;
  num=10;
  miarray = new int [num];

}

void draw(){
  background(#E5DCDD);
    pelotas();

}

void pelotas(){
   for (int i=0; i<miarray.length; i++) {  
   ellipse(50+i*40,40,40,40);  
}
}
```

Comment: que querra decir processing. Que hace cada una de esas funciones por ejemplo? y a que te referis con que no salgan todas juntas? se te dibujan todas juntas? quien las dibuja? puedes hacer que espere entre cada dibujo?

Comment: Hola. Processing es parecido a Java. Lo que aparece inicialmente son todas las pelotas juntas. Lo que necesito es que vayan apareciendo de una a una hasta llegar a las que deseo que en este caso son 10. Tienes alguna idea?

Comment: @gbianchi Hola, [Processing](https://processing.org/) es una lenguaje de programacion para crear dibujos y animaciones. El estructura del lenguaje es similar a Java.

Comment: @Luke Hola Luke, tienes alguna idea sobre el problema que comento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Nota: no tengo el recurso apropriado para ejecutar este codigo. Hay posibilidades que aun tiene errores menores.*

---

Processing tiene el funcion `second()` que devuelve el valor actual de segundo (0 - 59).
Con esto, podemos crear un 'cronometro' sencillo y manejar interval entre las elipses una a otro.

Y no necesitamos un array para guardar el numero de las elipses, solo necesitamos el variable `num`.

```
int i;
int num;

// variables relacionadas con el tiempo
int ahora; // almacena el segundo actual cuando lo actualizamos
int interval = 1; // interval en segundo


void setup(){
  size(500,200);
  background(#E5DCDD);

  i=0;
  num=10;

  ahora = second(); // obtiene el valor de segundo actual
}

void draw(){

  if(i < num)
  {
    if(second() - ahora >= interval){
        ellipse(50+i*40,40,40,40);
        i++;
        ahora = second(); // actualiza el 'cronometro'
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, lo he probado pero me parpadean las elipses y mi intención es que se queden una al lado de la otra y que no desaparezcan

Comment: @VeroSoler cortar el background(#E5DCDD) y pegarlo dentro de setup(). Por favor intentalo. Si funciona, dime, y voy a editar mi respuesta

Comment: Hola @Luke ahora si funciona! Mil gracias! Podría contactar contigo por otra via (privada) para consultarte sobre Processing? Con remuneración. Dime algo por favor

Comment: Hola @Luke si que funciona muchas gracias! podría contactarte por privado¿?

Comment: @VeroSoler He editado la respuesta. Si la solucion te sirve, haz clic en la marca al lado de la respuesta (debajo del contador de puntos a favor o en contra) para marcar la respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: @VeroSoler puede simplemente dejar su correo electronico en su perfil (acerca de mi) y te contactaré. Puede borrarlo mas tarde.

Comment: Hola @Luke, he dejado mi skype en mi perfil, ojalá me puedas contactar para hablarte sobre processing, saludos